# How to load Textures with Unity3d on Android

Tags: android, image, drop-down-menu, unity-game-engine

i am trying to get this really easy setup to work, and it works on my computer but not on Android.

After trying it for the whole day im now asking since i cant find a single example on the internet.

The setup:

- I have a lot of *.png files in a folder. Since the problem is with android i put them into a "StreamingAssets" folder
- I have a RawImage called "Overlay"
- I have a Dropdown called "Dropdown"

What should happen:
1. The Dropdown_script checks the StreamingAssets folder for all *.png files and adds every Filename to the dropdown options menu.
2. Once the user chooses one of the dropdown values my "Overlay" image changes its texture to the according file.

Pretty easy on PC ... impossible on android(with unity3d) as it seems.

My Dropdown Script:

```
public class DDScript : MonoBehaviour {

void Start () {
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("Dropdown");

    //Get all filenames 
    var info = new DirectoryInfo(Application.streamingAssetsPath);
    var fileInfo = info.GetFiles("*.png");

    //Clear the DropDown Menu Items from the Inspector
    obj.GetComponent<Dropdown>().options.Clear();
    //Make the first chosen item the first filename
    obj.GetComponent<Dropdown>().captionText.text = fileInfo[0].Name.Substring(0, fileInfo[0].Name.IndexOf("."));

    foreach (var file in fileInfo)
    {

        Dropdown.OptionData list = new Dropdown.OptionData(file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.IndexOf(".")));
        obj.GetComponent<Dropdown>().options.Add(list);
    }

}
```

Its not working. It is working on my Computer but it is just not working on Android. I know that under Android everything gets packed into a jar file and there is nothing like a folderstructure. StreamingAssets should still have the files but i can understand that this part maybe cant work. Which would not be that bad, since it just finds the names and puts it into an array, i could do that within the program by hand. Since i know from beforehand how much and which files will be in the folder and it wont change ever.

This is my Change Texture Method
It is invoked by the Dropdown OnValueChange so the "newOverlay" is simply the int from the Dropdown. For debugging purposes i set the filepath to a specific file. later it will change depending on newOverlay

```
public IENumerator SetOverlay(int newOverlay)
{
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("Overlay");
    img = (RawImage)obj.GetComponent<RawImage>();

    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "testfile.png");

    WWW www = new WWW(filePath);
    yield return www;
    img.texture = www.texture;

}
```

And i do not understand why this is not working!
The Documentation reads:
" This means that if you do not use Unity’s WWW class to retrieve the file then you will need to use additional software"
So using www is the right way. But it is not working!

No Texture gets loaded. i dont get the red questionmark, my image is just plain white. Please can someone help me here? Maybe i just cant see the forest due to all of the trees or the day was too long.

I really just cant believe that it is this hard to load a bunch of images that are within my apk file wiht unity :(

Thank you very much in advance

---

Edit: Solution (somehow)
First of all the problem was that System.IO.Path.Combine adds a back-slash between file and folder, but not between the folders themself!!!!

```
public void SetOverlay(int newOverlay)
{

    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("Overlay");
    img = (RawImage)obj.GetComponent<RawImage>();

    string filePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/testfile.png";

    WWW www = new WWW(filePath);

    while (!www.isDone)
    {}
    img.texture = www.texture;
    GameObject.Find("DebugText").GetComponent<Text>().text = filePath;

}
```

Havent found a solution to the Filename problem yet but im glad that this stupid "bug" is resolved

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the png files into the drawable folder and accessing them with BitmapFactory.decodeResources()?

Comment: I am using unity3d and android just for a short time. Are you telling me i can use my Android stanard functions and knowledge within unity somehow? Becasue i already have coded android apps using eclipse. And that would indeed make alot of stuff easier

Comment: I dont know if standard android code works within unity